# Sprite rotation algorithm

Tags: game-design, mathematics, algorithm, javascript, rotation

I'm making a game where you have to plot a function to hit certain objectives. I already made the plotting function and the animation to display a tiny missile that travels above the function. My problem is that the sprite must rotate following the function path. For example:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is the code. To trigger the current animation, just run the `animate()` function in your browser. In the `moveRocket()` function is where I render each frame of the animation. This is how I'm currently trying to get the rotation degrees:

`var rotationDegrees = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>sin título</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Geany 1.22" />
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        //Math stuff
        var height, width;
        var scale = 10; // A factor that does zoom in the function
        var landa = 0.15; // Gap between one point and another in the plotted function
        var fpsSpeed = 50; //secs per frame

        function xNeg () {
            return (-1)*(width / 2) //-x limit
        }

        function xPos() {
            return (+1)*(width / 2) //+y limit
        }


        function plot(context, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
            // translate the coordinates to the real canvas points, this is, (-10,-10) to (40.40) 
            // if we have a 100*100 canvas
            x1 = ((width / 2) + x1 * scale);
            x2 = ((width / 2) + x2 * scale);
            y1 = ((width / 2) - y1 * scale);
            y2 = ((width / 2) - y2 * scale);
            backgroundContext.moveTo(x1, y1);
            backgroundContext.lineTo(x2, y2);
            backgroundContext.stroke();
        }

        function f(x) {
            // the sample funcion
            return x*x;
        }

        function inverse(x) {
            // the inverse of the sample function, this is to not waste time rendering parts of the function
            // that aren't actually displayed.
            return Math.sqrt(x);
        }

        //Animation stuff
        var timer;
        var fps = 0;

        function addFrames(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
            addRocketFrame(x1,y1,x2,y2);
            //addEnemyHitFrame(x1,y1,x2,y2);
            //addSmockeTraceFrame(x1,y1,x2,y2);
        }

        function animate() {
            prepareLayer(rocketContext, rocketCanvas);
            timer=setTimeout('animate()', fpsSpeed);
            //HOT SPOT **
            moveRocket();
            //HOT SPOT **
            fps++;
            restoreLayer(rocketContext);
        }

        function restoreLayer(ctx) {
            ctx.restore();
        }

        function prepareLayer(ctx, canvas) {
            // Store the current transformation matrix
            ctx.save();
            // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
            ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            // Restore the transform
            ctx.restore();
        }

        //Rocket animation stuff

        var rocketFrames = new Array();
        var rocketFrameCounter = 0;

        //Render the rocket frames
        function moveRocket() {
            if (fps < rocketFrameCounter-1) {

                var frame = rocketFrames[fps];

                x1 = ((width / 2) + frame.x1 * scale);
                y1 = ((width / 2) - frame.y1 * scale);
                x2 = ((width / 2) + frame.x2 * scale);
                y2 = ((width / 2) - frame.y2 * scale);

                var rotationDegrees = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1); //Trying to get the rotation degrees...
                var rocketImage = document.getElementById("rocket");

                rocketContext.drawImage(rocketImage, x1, y1);
                //rocketContext.rotate(rotationDegrees);

            }
        }

        function addRocketFrame(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
            var frame = { x1:x1,
                          y1:y1,
                          x2:x2,
                          y2:y2};
            rocketFrames[rocketFrameCounter++] = frame;
        }

        window.onload = function() {
            rocketCanvas = document.getElementById("rocketlayer");
            rocketContext = rocketCanvas.getContext("2d");

            backgroundCanvas = document.getElementById("background");
            backgroundContext = backgroundCanvas.getContext("2d");

            height = 600;
            width = 800;

            // Start plotting the function
            for ( var x1 = -inverse(xPos()); x1 < inverse(xPos()); x1 += landa) {
                var y1 = f(x1); //from
                var x2 = x1 + landa;
                var y2 = f(x2); //from
                plot(backgroundContext, x1, y1, x2, y2);
                //Add the frames that we are gonna to use to the animation
                addFrames(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            }
        };
    </script>

    <div id="container" style="position: relative;">
        <canvas id="background" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
        <canvas id="rocketlayer" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"  width="800" height="600"></canvas>
    </div>
    <img width="13" height="50" id="rocket" title="" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
</body>

</html>
```

My problem is that when I try to rotate the sprite with this line:

`var rotationDegrees = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);`

This doesn't give me the right rotation degrees, I searched and I think that this is the right algorithm. So any clue of why this isn't working?

Comment: You haven't described any problem. What is your question? What is *not* working?

Comment: This appears to be asking "how do I move the sprite in the direction of travel," which is a duplicate question. If not, please edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: @astinx your edit to explicitly say your question triggered a reopen vote, but your question is still a duplicate of another one with an identical topic.  Also, you clearly know the correct method, but are having trouble implementing it.  That makes it a question about debugging your code, which is also off-topic.  If you need assistance nailing down the problem, try the [chat].